# Conflict between styled-components and Webpack 5 Federated Modules (Invalid hook call)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, styled-components

Been trying out Webpack's 5 Module Federation and came upon this problem. Tried many approaches but none seem to work. Basically when I try to use `styled-components` on a federated module, I get React's `Invalid hook call` error.

Here is a repository which tries to reproduce the problem:

- https://github.com/oncet/federated-modules-styled-components

I wonder if I'm missing something or if this is some kind of bug.

Comment: Made a bug report https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3302

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved by telling Webpack to use React as a singleton.

In `foo/webpack.config.js` I changed `shared` to `[{ react: { singleton: true } }]`.

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'foo',
  filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
  exposes: {
    './Foo': './src/App',
  },
  shared: [{ react: { singleton: true } }],
})
```

Big thanks to [Zach Jackson](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3302#issuecomment-707431329)!